# IntelliJ Grails Support + Git

Tags: git, grails, intellij-idea, groovy

1) So I need to create a project using Grails + Groovy + Git using IntelliJ but it seems my IntelliJ doesn't have Grails included, is there any way I can add it?

It shows up like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jrnp8YE.png]

2) Also when I installed Grails it installed somewhere on C:\ and I think for it to get saved on my Git repo it needs to be inside of it. How can I make this work?

3) Haven't got to the Groovy part yet so if anyone can give me any heads up on configuration it would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR: Need to create a project with IntelliJ using Grails + Groovy, and store it on my Git repo, need config instructions.

Comment: If you have ultimate edition and the grails still doesnot show up, you can later add grails lib through project structure inside of File menu.

Answer (score 2):

> > but it seems my IntelliJ doesn't have Grails included

As mentioned in the [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/grails.html)

> This feature is supported in the Ultimate edition only.

As opposed to groovy: see "[Getting Started with Groovy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/getting-started-with-groovy.html)"

Beside that, you can follow [How to get a Grails Project into Git](http://jyotirmaya.blogspot.fr/2012/10/how-to-get-grails-project-into-git.html), and make sure to do a `git init .` inside your grail root project.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you downloaded community version of IntelliJ idea. 
Download ultimate version of idea.